# I'm really confused on the formula $Q=mL$ on phase change

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, ice

> "A 6.00 kg piece of solid copper metal at an initial temperature T
> is placed with 2.00 kg of ice that is initially at -20.0°C. The ice is in an
> insulated container of negligible mass and no heat is exchanged with the
> surroundings. After thermal equilibrium is reached, there is 1.20 kg of
> ice and 0.80 kg of liquid water. What was the initial temperature of the
> piece of copper?"

this is the problem.

in the Qgain = m_ice * c_ice * temp_ice + m_water * L (334*10^3)

but why mass of water in the formula Q=mL

i thought ice is gaining heat and melting to water so shouldn't it be mass of ice?

Comment: Why would it be the mass of the ice be used in a latent heat formula? You started off with ice, so any remaining ice **hasn't** undergone a phase change. Any water at the end **has** undergone a phase change.

Comment: im not sure cause i use chegg and they said it 0.8*334*10^3. i thought it was 2*334*10^3

Comment: Welcome to Physics StackExchange, please format your mathematical expressions using MathJax/LaTeX for proper display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the equation  $Q=mL$, note that $L$ is the *latent heat of fusion*, or the energy required to change the state of a solid (in this case, ice) to a liquid (water). Here, 0.8 kg of ice has changed phase to water.

So it makes sense that the mass of the ice appears in the equation.

Comment: no like in chegg they use the mass of water in that equation. They did  0.8 * 334*10^3

Comment: Yes, but 0.8 kg of ice has been changed to water.

Comment: omg thank you so much now it make sense.

Comment: That’s ok. Good luck with your studies. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ice is gaining heat ineeded, then as it reaches temperature of 0 celsiuis degrees it starts to melt. But the mass of melted ice is equal to the mass of water which appeared. Conservation of mass : )